# Which SATA power cable is standard?, and why are there 2 standards?

Tags: ssd, power-supply, hardware-failure, sata, cable

Pictured are two visually identical SATA Power cables, meant to connect to a PSU (the other end of each cable, not pictured, connects to a SATA drive). They're only distinguishable by the metal inside each pin (hard to see in person, easy to see in the photo attached).

Which one of these two is considered standard? From a hardware design perspective, why was a 2nd standard introduced?

(In case you're curious, yes, I destroyed an SSD by not noticing this).

[image]

Comment: The middle top peg looks slightly different. I'm not sure if it's just bad lighting or damage caused by forcing it into the wrong hole.

Comment: Those are not SATA connectors by any stretch. https://www.google.com/search?q=SATA+Power&source=lnms&tbm=isch They could be EPS or CPU_12V but not SATA. They are likely PSU dependant and you shouldn't mix cables from one unit with another purely for this reason.

Comment: No, they're not. They're power cables for your PSU units that happen to have SATA on the other end. The end pictured is a generic [molex](http://www.molex.com) wire-to-board connector and the pinout is whatever the PSU manufacturer decides. SATA is a specification that defines connector pinouts and what you have there is not part of that specification.

Comment: The google search you cite shows this exact cable. You're right, they're not a SATA *data* cable, but the term Sata Power Cable is correct, as these provide power to a SATA drive. I'm just showing the non-sata end in this picture. The user manual for my PSU refers to them as Sata Power Cables, and the back of the PSU itself (where these cables connect) is labeled SATA.

Answer (score 6):

This is not a standardized plug at all: The other end might carry a standard SATA Power connector, but this end looks like it is intended to plug into a "modular" power supply - those connections are not standardized and highly vendor (and even model-) specific.

Not being standardized means, you have to buy new cables from the original vendor if you want to extend your setup.

**EDIT**

The previous paragraph was originally prefixed with "Honi qui mal y pense" - this can be translated as "Ashamed should be, whoever thinks bad of this" and is used in Europe (where I am from) to say "They did that on purpose". I apologize if SO users from the US were led to misread this as to be ashamed for being in that situation